# Connecting usb keyboard, bluez-simple-agent missing

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, bluez

I'm attempting to connect my Logitech k810 usb keyboard to my Debian Jessie machine.

Connecting using [this guide](http://blog.chschmid.com/?p=1537) has worked well in the past.

The problem is that a step in the guide requires the package bluez-simple-agent.

Apparently that package is no longer a part of bluez.

How can I install bluez-simple-agent or something equivalent?

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu 15.10 https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-connect-device.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working with

```
bluetoothctl -a
```

I guess the `-a` option is the replacement for bluez-simple-agent. From `man bluetoothctl`:

```
-a, --agent=CAPABILITY Register agent handler
```

Comment: Just had the same problem, but it does not work: `bluetoothctl -a hci0 00:07:61:74:56:F0 [NEW] Controller 08:0A:3A:79: blub [default] Failed to register agent: org.bluez.Error.InvalidArguments [bluetooth]#`.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 16.04:

I opened blueman from the dash. 
Set my logitech 810 into pairing mode. 
Blueman detected it in the gui. 
Right click to trust keyboard. 
Right click to setup -> pair. 
Pairing numbers will pop up on your screen. 
Type them in and hit enter on Logitch 810. 
Then it was working.